Android disable past week Sundays from calendar picker
Need to disable the past week's Sunday from the Calendar.
Below is the logic I tried, it disabled the future week Sunday but I need the past week.
 var sunday: Calendar?
 val weekends: ArrayList<Calendar> = ArrayList()
 val weeks = 5
 var i =0
        while (i < (weeks * 7)) {
            sunday = Calendar.getInstance()
            sunday.add(
                Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,
                (Calendar.SUNDAY - sunday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 + i)
            )
            weekends.add(sunday)
            i += 7
        }
     val disabledDays = weekends.toTypedArray<Calendar>()
     datePickerDialog.disabledDays = disabledDays



